# elastic search highlighted text with paragraph to python list

Tags: python, elasticsearch

How to pass highlighted words with full text to python list?

i tried but its not working.

```
res = es.search(index="database_db", body={"query": {"match": {'full_texts':{"query":es_query, "operator": "and"}}},"highlight" : {"pre_tags" : ["<b>"],"post_tags" : ["</b>"],"fields" : {"query" : {}}}}, size=50)

result_list = []

for hit in res['hits']['hits']:
    result_list.append("%(full_texts)s" % hit["_source"])
```

> I mean i can't do google like highlighted results by elastic search. So how to do that?

Maybe  `"%(full_texts)s" % hit["_source"]` this part is wrong?

desired output is add html "`<b>`" tag in paragraph:

Alan Turing, in full Alan Mathison Turing, (born June 23, 1912, London, England—died June 7, 1954, Wilmslow, Cheshire), **`<b>` British mathematician `</b>`** and logician who made major contributions to mathematics, cryptanalysis, logic, philosophy, and mathematical biology and also to the new areas later named computer science